# Scene 1, Layer 'Script', Frame 1, Line 9 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Flammer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to code a visible = true/false for a movieclip, when you hold the mouse button down, it's visible and when you let go off the mouse button it's not visible anymore!
But I can't get it to work, have a look and help me please :)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;

var mouseIsDown = false;
var speed = 0; 
var score = 0;
var flames:MovieClip = new Flammer()
Flammer.visible = false;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicked);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, unclicked);




function clicked(m:MouseEvent){
mouseIsDown = true;
}
function unclicked(m:MouseEvent){
mouseIsDown = false;

}
function mainLoop(e:Event) {
score = score + 10;
output.text = "Score: " + score;
    if (mouseIsDown) {
    speed -= 2;
    Flammer.visible = true;


} else {
    speed += 2;


}
if (speed > 10) speed = 10;
if (speed < -10) speed = -5;
Player.y += speed;



for (var i = 0; i<numChildren; i++) {
    if(getChildAt(i) is Block || getChildAt(i) is Boundray) {
        var b = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if(b.hitTestObject(Player)) {
            trace("Hit");
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);


        }

    } 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That specific error is tell you that on line 9 where you have `Flammer.visible = false;` there is no such object called `Flammer`, that's a class.  You want the instanced object.  Correctly written would be

`flames.visible = false;`

You'd also want to fix it on line 29, where you repeat the same issue.